# Mixing .NET Core and Framework in same solution - System.Data.Entity Issue

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-5, .net-framework-version, .net-standard-2.0

I am giving our legacy .NET 4 Framework libraries a new entry via .NET Core WebAPIs.
Unfortunately, I am stuck at an issue at runtime (while loading dependency container) in the webapi project (net core):

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Entity'
```

I tried explicitly adding reference to Entity in webapi project but then I get BadImageReferenceException, I am aware this library is discontinued in net core.

The Legacy .NET 4 Framework library has extensive use of EntityFramework (5.0.0) so System.Data.Entity is heavily used. I tried to port these libraries to .netstandard but a lot of code change is required.

Any options I have to avoid (heavy) code change where I can use the shiny new api in core and supporting libraries untouched?

Comment: Are you trying to reference your old code directly from the asp.net core project? What is your target framework in the asp.net core project?

Comment: @PSGuy I am targeting .NET 5 or happy with .NET Core 3.1 too

Comment: update to EF6, that EF version also runs on .net core

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks that seemed to have done the trick! The front end now runs successfully with minimal refactoring in the dependant legacy class libraries. Thank You!

Comment: @Avais ok, I posted it as answer, so that [you can accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to "close" the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF5 is not compatible with .Net Core. The only classic EF version that runs on .Net Core is [Entity Framework 6 since Version 6.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/what-is-new/#ef-630):

> - Support for .NET Core 3.0 
>    The EntityFramework package now targets .NET Standard 2.1 in addition to .NET Framework 4.x.

So update from [EF5 to EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/what-is-new/upgrading-to-ef6) to fix your issues.